# Quartz Composer barcode scanner

Tags: plugins, barcode-scanner, quartz-composer

Are there any Quartz Composer barcode scanner plugins that can run on Leopard (10.5)? I need something that can scan the type of barcode found on the back of books; I've seen a DataMatrix plugin using libdmtx which scans some other types of barcode.

Comment: what specific kind of barcodes are you looking for? EAN8? EAN13? UPC-E? OneCode? PharmaCode? MSI? KIX?

if it's any help : http://www.tamperco.com/v/vspfiles/assets/images/barcode_types.jpg

Comment: Are you looking for a driver? I would think that the scanner behaves like a generic USB-keyboard input device, since I've used such scanners and their scanning outputs as if the resultant numbers are being typed via a keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I can't do comments yet but have you tried :

http://kineme.net/wiki/ThirdPartyQuartzComposerPlugins